Specifying label directions for different sectors in circos plot
I am trying to create to circos plot using the circlize package in R. I want the labels on the first two sectors to be bending inside (facing = "bending.inside") and those on the remaining sectors to be pointing outwards in the clockwise direction (facing = "clockwise"). From the vignette, it looks like only a single parameter can be specified in the facing argument. Is there a way to assign different label directions for different sectors? Please help.
Here's a part of the code that I used to specify the direction of the labels:
library(grid)
library(gridBase)
library(ComplexHeatmap)

circos.trackPlotRegion(track.index = 1, 
                   panel.fun = function(x, y) {
                     xlim = get.cell.meta.data("xlim")
                     ylim = get.cell.meta.data("ylim")
                     sector.name = get.cell.meta.data("sector.index")
                     circos.text(CELL_META$xcenter, 
                                 ylim[1] + cm_h(25), 
                                 sector.name, 
                                 facing = "clockwise",
                                 niceFacing = TRUE, 
                                 adj = c(0, 0.5),
                                 cex = 1.8)
                   }, bg.border = NA)

